# Java create custom exception class with specific status code

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception

In Spring Boot, I create custom exception class with specific status code, and I call it to throw exception with code: 100 and message: "No have content" at controller, but output still returns "status": 500 and "error": "Internal Server Error"

**AppException.java**

```
public class AppException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final Integer code;

    public AppException(Integer code, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping()
    public ApiResponseDto getAllUsers(Pageable pageable) {
        Page<User> users = userService.getAllUsers(pageable);

        if (users.getSize() < 0) {
            throw new AppException(100, "No have content");
        }

        return new ApiResponseDto(HttpStatus.OK.value(), users);
    }
```

**Actual Output:**

```
{
    "timestamp": 1550987372934,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "com.app.core.exception.AppException",
    "message": "No have content",
    "path": "/api/user"
}
```

**My expectation:**

```
{
    "timestamp": 1550987372934,
    "status": 100,
    "error": "No have content",
    "exception": "com.app.core.exception.AppException",
    "message": "No have content",
    "path": "/api/user"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you want to have global exception handling for your API, and prefer to have custom error responses, you can add [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html):

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({ ApiException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<ApiErrorResponse> handleApiException(ApiException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ApiErrorResponse(ex.getStatus(), ex.getMessage(), Instant.now()), ex.getStatus());
    }
}

// you can put any information you want in ApiErrorResponse 
public class ApiErrorResponse {

    private final HttpStatus status;
    private final String message;
    private final Instant timestamp;

    public ApiError(HttpStatus status, String message, Instant timestamp) {
        this.status= status;
        this.message = message;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public HttpStatus getStatus() { 
        return this.status; 
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }

    public Instant getTimestamp() {
        return this.timestamp;
    }
}

// your custom ApiException class
public class ApiException extends RuntimeException {

    private final HttpStatus status;

    public ApiException(HttpStatus status, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.status = status;
    }

    public HttpStatus getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but throw new AppException(100, "No have content"); is example.
Because, I want to use AppException class for many my status code in project

Comment: @Tony I updated the answer in case you want to have global exception handling for your API, and prefer to have custom error responses.

Comment: thanks, but I want to throw exception at anywhere service class, java class, ..., not return for controller.
btw, using @ControllerAdvice it also not return exactly status code I put for ApiException(Integer code, String message).
Can you suggest me other way?

Comment: @Tony Exception could be thrown anywhere in your code. Also use `HttpStatus` instead of `Integer` inside `ApiException`.

Comment: Why are there 2 public classes in the same file?

Answer (score 3):

If you need a limited number of different error-messages or you want to reuse the same one several times, then that's all you need:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CONTINUE, reason = "No have content")
public class AppException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

No need of any extra classes and handlers. Your code will be clear and simple.

You can simply raise it like this:

```
throw new AppException();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

1. **ExceptionHandler**

   You can add a `@ExceptionHandler` annotated method in your controller:

   ```
   @ExceptionHandler({ CustomException1.class, CustomException2.class })
   public void handleException() {
   //
   }
   ```
2. **HandlerExceptionResolver**

   You can also implement a custom resolver to intercept all exceptions and handle them globally by overriding the `doResolveException` method

More detail on the above two approaches can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring